# IAR Embedded Workbench: stdarg.h isn't preprocessed

Tags: c, iar

I'm building a c-language application, using *IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM 7.40*.
I'm using *libclang* to get an *AST* (abstract syntax tree) representation of my c-code.
For that, I'm preprocessing my source-code.
The problem is with `#include <stdarg.h>` - **it doesn't get expanded**.

Original code snippet:

```
int before_stdarg = 1;
#include <stdarg.h>
int after_stdarg = 2;
va_list args;
#include "func1.h"
...
```

Preprocessed code snippet:

```
#line 1 "source\\App\\func1.c"
int before_stdarg = 1;
#include <stdarg.h>
int after_stdarg = 2;
va_list args;
#line 1 "C:\\testAppC\\source\\App\\func1.h"
...
```

Viewing stdarg.h:

```
#ifdef __ICCARM__
#error "Reading built-in header-file. If you used upper case, try #include <stdarg.h>"
#endif
```

A second issue: where is `va_list` defined?
commenting out `#include <stdarg.h>` results in a compilation error: `Error[Pe020]: identifier "va_list" is undefined`

What am I missing?

**Update, due to comments:**
The Q is not for IAR EWARM newbies, as the marked answer can hint.
The issue occurs on any minimal hello-world example, simply by adding the `#include <stdarg.h>`, without even using it!
The preprocess command is a copy-paste of the regular build command, with the `--preprocess=l PATH_TO_PREPROCESSED_OUTPUT_FILE` addition:

```
PS C:\testAppC> iccarm.exe source\App\func1.c -DSTM32L476xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.2\arm\CMSIS\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.2\arm\inc\c" -I"source\App" -I"source\Device" --char_is_signed --cpu=Cortex-M4 --debug --dlib_config  "C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.2\arm\INC\c\DLib_Config_Normal.h" --endian=little --fpu=None --no_clustering --no_code_motion --no_cse --no_inline --no_scheduling --no_tbaa --no_unroll -On -e -o testAppC\Obj --preprocess=l C:\testAppC\.aurora\tmp\func1.c.i
```

Comment: Per [section 7.16 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16), the type `va_list` is declared in `stdarg.h`.  This is why you get a compilation error when you attempt to use that type without including the header.  I can't speak with any authority to why the preprocessor does not expand the header, but you seem to have established that "does not expand" is very different in your case from "ignores".

Comment: It think it is some compiler-specific quirk which is recognizing this header as "built-in" and assuming it's functionality provided by the compiler without actually using the header.

Comment: `I'm using libclang to get an AST` - how? `I'm preprocessing my source-code` - how? `it doesn't get expanded` - as a result of what command? How to replicate the behaviour you are getting. Ok, let's imagine I have installed the workbench, what should I do to have the stdarg not expanded? How did you run the preprocessor? What options did you use? Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of steps you took to reproduce the problems you are having.

Comment: There should be no reason to need stdarg.h in an embedded system. Its presence means you are either using printf, sprintf or user-defined variadic functions. In either case, a certain sign of bad code.

Comment: @Lundin wowow, that's a bit broad statement, it is an ARM microprocessor not a uC with 4 bits of ram.

Comment: Antti Haapala - I simply smiled regarding comment by @Lundin. Thanks for standing up :-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Memory consumption, execution speed, program safety. There are very few functions in any programming language that are more dangerous. In embedded systems specifically, programmers tend to use them either because they don't know how to implement a serial port interface, or because they are too lazy to do so, or alternatively because they don't know how to convert integers to text. None of the alternatives are flattering.

Comment: @Lundin there are embedded systems outside automotive/industrial industry. Some might even use printf. ;)

Comment: I have embedded systems that *speak*.

Comment: I agree that va_list is probably not supported in misra 26262. I'm using it as part of the c-language 'Greatest' regression-testing-framework. As you grow, you learn to wait with your assumptions, before jumping to conclusions...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Obviously the term "embedded system" is broad and subjective. A PC mounted inside a custom enclosure isn't an embedded system in my book, but that's just me.

Comment: @RamiRosenbaum ISO 26262 -> MISRA-C -> complete ban of stdio.h in production code. Furthermore, the (A)SIL standards dictate that you are not allowed to have any code in your project which doesn't have an execution path in the live production binary. So managing a test build through compiler switches etc won't do, you'll need different, separate branches for test code. Even still, writing test cases with stdio.h is questionable, because it will bloat up all that is real-time and you end up testing something else that isn't the actual product. stdio.h is a bug factory, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iccarm 7.40 the `stdarg.h` in the filesystem is only a stub file. The varargs machinery is built into the compiler and activated by the `#include <stdarg.h>` directive. This is also why this include directive is not expanded when using the `--preprocess` command line option. This was changed recently and as of iccarm 8.40 the compiler uses the `stdarg.h` from the file system.

Answer (score 1):

As a general remark, the *headers* specified in `<...>` need not be separate files on disk, but can be built in to the compiler, and need only be expanded during the preprocessing phase of the compilation *as if* they were code pasted in the place of the `#include` directive.

In fact, the standard says that the *other* include form of `"..."` includes *source files*, so the standard itself does not even use a term "header file" at all - there are only **headers** or **source files**.

Comment: I thought that <...> just includes the build-system include-paths, while "..."  uses only the user include-paths. Interesting... thanks.

Comment: @RamiRosenbaum that is "implementation-defined". `"..."` includes source files by given name, and if not found, then *headers* by that name as if placed in `<...>`.

Comment: I guess it is just the IDEs for which the header contents are placed in external files, so that it is easier to autocomplete stuff, hence the reversal mentioned by Johan....